# Calculating roots of a perturbed polynomial

Tags: polynomials, numerical-methods, roots, matlab

Given the following polynomial:

> $ p(x)=25x^8 +85x^7 +181x^6 +238x^5 +226x^4 +142x^3 +61x^2 +13x+1
> $

Which factors as $(x^2 + x + 1)^3(5x + 1)^2$, (It has a triple complex root and their conjugates and a double real root) I am trying to obtain the roots of the perturbed polynomial

> $h(x) = p(x) + 10^{−8}x^5$

I know obtaining roots of a polinomial is an ill-posed problem. I am using Maehly's method in Matlab.

Matlab gives the roots:

`-5.000568859054557e-01 + 8.664727042796275e-01i
    -5.000568859054557e-01 - 8.664727042796275e-01i
    -5.003588172119005e-01 + 8.657523017471233e-01i
    -5.003588172119005e-01 - 8.657523017471233e-01i
    -4.995842968797133e-01 + 8.658512052028565e-01i
    -4.995842968797133e-01 - 8.658512052028565e-01i
    -2.000004647944056e-01 + 0.000000000000000e+00i
    -1.999995352114569e-01 + 0.000000000000000e+00i`

Using Maehly's method I obtain poor convergence. How can I deduce if the roots are multiple or they are very close?

I have already evaluated the roots in both the derivative polynomial $Dp$ and $p$ and, my conclusions are that none of the roots is double, because I obtain, for example:

$$   p(-2.000000000026995e-01)=-3.200106846179551e-12$$
and
$$   Dp(-2.000000000026995e-01)=1.776356839400251e-15$$

Do you think it is safe to asume that this root is not multiple? If so, How should I compute the root that is very close to this one?

Comment: According to [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=0%3D25x%5E8+%2B85x%5E7+%2B181x%5E6+%2B(238%2B10%5E(-8))x%5E5+%2B226x%5E4+%2B142x%5E3+%2B61x%5E2+%2B13x%2B1), the 8 roots are all unique.  Though they are extremely close.

Comment: Given any polynomial $f(x)$ and one of its root $a$ with multiplicity $m$. If you perturb $f(x)$ by a polynomial $\epsilon g(x)$ with $g(a) \ne 0$, the root $a$ will split into $m$ simple roots. For small $\epsilon$, the leading behavior of the new roots are $a = a + \left(-\epsilon \frac{m! g(a)}{f^{(m)}(a)}\right)^{1/m} e^{\frac{2\pi k i}{m}}$ where $k \le 0 < m$. Since the perturbation you have $g(x) = x^5$ doesn't vanish on the roots of $p(x)$, if $\epsilon = 10^{-8}$ is small enough, your roots will be simple.

Comment: @achillehui,, please, can you tell me a bibliography to look at this result of the perturbation of $f(x)$ by the polynomial $\epsilon g(x)$, which you mention above.